# How to bind a html to a Gridview column?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

I have searched about this a lot in google. But, i didn't get any clue.
Thanks to you all in advance.

**Question:** i have a html source in my datatable column.when it binds with my gridview, i need to show that html output in  my gridview column. Is that Possible **?**

**current output:**

[image]

**My aspx code:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();
    dtEmployees.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(System.String)));
    dtEmployees.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(System.String)));
    dtEmployees.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HomePhone", typeof(System.String)));
    dtEmployees.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CellPhone", typeof(System.String)));
    dtEmployees.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(System.String)));

    DataRow drEmpDetail = dtEmployees.NewRow();
    drEmpDetail["FirstName"] = "Tony";
    drEmpDetail["LastName"] = "Greg";
    drEmpDetail["HomePhone"] = "000-000-0000";
    drEmpDetail["CellPhone"] = "000-000-0000";
    drEmpDetail["Address"] = "Lane 1 Suite # 2 &lt;br&gt;";
  }
```

Just for example,In the Address column i have given html tag for the "break tag".But in the output it just displays like a string, the result is not as expected.

**Note:** I don't want to use the Template field instead of BoundField.

Comment: do you mind using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using - `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Lane 1 Suite # 2 &lt;br&gt;")`

The markup will be,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("Address").ToString()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Set `HtmlEncode` to false in your bounfield property

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="YourDataField" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

[BoundField HTML Encode Property MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: will this be HTML output. No @Damien, it wont be

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the System.Net namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Design your gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName"  DataField="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LastName"  DataField="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="HomePhone"  DataField="HomePhone" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CellPhone"  DataField="CellPhone" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address"  DataField="Address" HtmlEncode="false" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```